# Getting run-time error '3075' syntax error (missing operator) in query expression

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am trying to build a library management database in ms access. When i fill up the form and click add then i get run-time error 3075. Can you please help me find out the problem? Thank you in advance.

```
 Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()

'add data to table

Dim strInsert As String
strInsert = "INSERT INTO Library (ID_Label, [Book Name_Label], Author_Label, Publishers_Label, Category_Label, Year_Label, [Book type_Label], [Page Count_Label], [Unique ID_Label], [Shelf Number_Label], Comments_Label, [Lend To_Label], [Phone Number_Label]) " & _
" VALUES(" & Me.txtId & ",'" & Me.txtBookName & ",'" & Me.txtAuthor & ",'" & Me.txtPublishers & ",'" & Me.cmbCategory & ",'" & Me.cmbYear & ",'" & Me.cmbBookType & ",'" & Me.txtPageCount & ",'" & Me.txtUniqueId & ",'" & Me.txtShelfNumber & ",'" & Me.txtComments & ",'" & Me.txtLendTo & ",'" & Me.txtPhoneNumber & "')"
Debug.Print strInsert,
CurrentDb.Execute strInsert, dbFailOnError

'refresh data in list on form
frmRecordNewSub.Form.Requery
```

Answer (score 1):

This: `'" & Me.txtComments & ",` piece should probably be `'" & Me.txtComments & "',`

If you want us to debug a dynamically created SQL string, please `Debug.Print` it (this one was simple).

If you want to avoid such errors (and SQL injection), use parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, nearly every one of your input values has unpaired single quotes.

Try this:

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()

'add data to table

Dim strInsert As String
strInsert = "INSERT INTO Library (ID_Label, [Book Name_Label], Author_Label, Publishers_Label, Category_Label, Year_Label, [Book type_Label], [Page Count_Label], [Unique ID_Label], [Shelf Number_Label], Comments_Label, [Lend To_Label], [Phone Number_Label]) " & _
" VALUES(" & Me.txtId & ", '" & Me.txtBookName & "', '" & Me.txtAuthor & "', '" & Me.txtPublishers & "', '" & Me.cmbCategory & "', '" & Me.cmbYear & "', '" & Me.cmbBookType & "', '" & Me.txtPageCount & "', '" & Me.txtUniqueId & "', '" & Me.txtShelfNumber & "', '" & Me.txtComments & "', '" & Me.txtLendTo & "', '" & Me.txtPhoneNumber & "')"
Debug.Print strInsert,
CurrentDb.Execute strInsert, dbFailOnError

'refresh data in list on form
frmRecordNewSub.Form.Requery
```